# What is  a "Center Of Mass" issue of a Gorillapod?

Tags: terminology, definition, statics, torque, stability

I read somewhere that a [Gorillapod](http://joby.com/gorillapod/slrzoom) may have "[Center Of Mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)" issues when used with the long lenses.

So, I wish to understand what is a "Center Of Mass" issue?

I have to clarify that I am NOT a physics student nor I ever intend to be. Answers in a layman's language would be appreciated.

Comment: No terrifying formulas please. :)

Comment: You're certainly welcome to ask for a simple explanation, but I just wanted to remind everyone that this is ostensibly an expert-level site: we reserve the right to use formulas when it's appropriate to do so ;-)

Comment: Long lenses often (typically?) have a tripod attachment point at a point just short of half-way to the end of the lens. The center of mass of the lens is at half-way, but the tripod attachment point is placed where the center of mass of the lens+camera (sorry, equation!) might be, for a typical camera with which the lens might be used. Given such an attachment point, the location of the center of mass is probably not too much of a problem, however long lenses are also relatively heavy, and a gorillapod is intentionally very light, and that can be a problem in itself.

Comment: If you want physicists to help you, then perhaps you should think twice before calling their bread-and-butter "terrifying"...

Comment: @ptomato think about getting some sense of humour. The word terrifying was for myself. I am ignorant in this field, so I would be terrified with the big formulas. This doesn't mean that formulas are "bad" or anything like that.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Would you feel equally confident saying "I cant read so good, please, no scary big words! Ha ha!" It's appaling that there exist people who are illiterate regarding mathematics, and it's appaling that they aren't doing anything about it.

Comment: @RonMaimon *"Would you feel equally confident saying "I cant read so good, please, no scary big words! Ha ha!""* Not a native English speaker am I, so definitely if you use big words I may not be able to understand them. But, it won't take much time for me to look their meanings in the dictionary. I am not a Maths student, so I can't say the same regarding Maths. Also, it appalling that people here feel the need to start nitpicking on a simply harmless joke.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: The point is that one must be ever ready to learn more words, and similarly, to learn more mathematics. Both are open-ended projects, but for some reason nobody says "I know enough words, I won't learn anymore", but people say "I know enough math, I won't learn any more". This is a destructive attitude. It's not a joke, it's an expression of a sentiment which makes technical matters the subject of others, and says it isn't important to know anything about them.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I'm sorry, I think we got off on the wrong foot here. I'm not trying to pick on you and I think your question is good. I'm not blaming you, because most people don't realize it, but that attitude comes across as aggressively insulting, at least to me (I don't know if I can speak for others.) I was trying to point that out in a light-hearted way, but I failed. Please don't let me discourage you from asking other questions, because we do enjoy explaining physics to non-physicists and believe it or not, we do try to avoid formulas when we are doing so ;-)

Comment: I wrote a little essay about that a few years ago: http://ptomato.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/hurdles-even-here/

Comment: @ptomato Thanks for the polite response. *"but that attitude comes across as aggressively insulting,"* Different people have different sense of humors, so I think people should be given some benefit of doubt - Actually, your statement sounded like a *'angry order'* to me. A better way to say the same would have been IMO, *"The word terrifying sounds offending to me when used on physics terms"*, and I would have simply apologized.

Comment: Secondly, Maths is not the most important subject on the Earth for "living" IMO. It is a matter of "choice", so I find it very irritating when certain people say *"It's appaling that there exist people who are illiterate regarding mathematics"*. :duh: Maths hasn't been my prime subject of interest ever, and I am still alive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to guess without seeing Gorillapod in use, but my guess would be the following:

Center of mass could be understood as an average position of the mass of the object.  In order for an object to be in stable equilibrium, its center of muss must be *vertically above the area*, which is enclosed by contact points of tripod's legs with the ground.  If you use elongated objects, center of mass is far from the point where camera is attached to the tripod and there is large likelihood that it won't be above the specified area, meaning that the tripod together with the object could fall over.

The point is that tripod is designed in a way that center of mass of the object it supports is fairly close to the attachment point, and of long lenses this is not so.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have added the link for the Gorillapod in the question. Will this problem of center mass not be same for all tripods of this height?

Comment: Yes, assuming the legs of the tripods cover roughly the same area and meet the ground at the same point.

Comment: Problem of center of mass exists for any tripod and for any object who has relatively high center of mass and relatively small area of contact with the ground (humans are very prone to center of mass problem, dogs aren't).

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from Pygmalion's answer a graphical explaination can be as below
(Warning! - Representation may be a bit wierd and out of proportion)

Initially without the camera this is the case
[image]
After camera with long lenses is placed the COM (centre of mass) shifts upwards and outwards as below
[image]
This *might* be the "Centre of Mass" issue you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Stand on your tiptoes and hold your hands out. You will discover what center of mass issues means. Basically gravity is pushing down on the camera/lens and it needs to be supported *directly* underneath where gravity is acting (center of gravity).